# How to sort a list<string> / array of string version number?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, version-sort

I have a list of strings of version (see photo), and I'd like to sort them in descending order.

[image]

I've seen a few solutions using Version class to compare them, but I can't think of any solution that sort a whole list like this. What is the least complicated way to achieve this?

Comment: A `List<Version>` will be simplest.  Strings containing numerals wont sort list numbers.  Alternatively, find/use a Natural Sort

Comment: Side note: Please don't add "thank you" and "searched alot" text to your posts. To demonstrate research effort provide links to approaches you've tried with brief explanation why it did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

what is wrong with this simple implementation?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ver = new List<Version>();

            ver.Add(new Version("3.5"));
            ver.Add(new Version("3.15"));
            ver.Add(new Version("3.10"));
            ver.Add(new Version("3.1"));

            ver.Sort();
            ver.Reverse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't come to my mind. When I read about Version class, I thought I need to compare only between 2 objects

Answer (score 7):

you can use IComparable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              List<string> data = new List<string>{
                "3.5.0.1", "3.4.1.9", "3.4.1.56", "3.4.1.55", "3.4.1.46",
                "3.4.1.45", "3.4.1.44", "3.4.1.30", "3.4.1.3", "3.4.1.22",
                "3.4.1.2", "3.4.1.11", "3.4.1.0", "3.4.0.7", "3.4.0.3",
                "3.4.0.1", "3.3.0.8", "3.3.0.4", "3.3.0.0", "3.2.0.9",
                "3.2.0.6", "3.2.0.3", "3.2.0.27", "3.2.0.20", "3.2.0.15",
                "3.2.0.1", "3.2.0.0", "3.1.0.7", "3.1.0.15", "3.1.0.14"
              };
              List<SortPara> sortPara = data.Select(x => new SortPara(x)).ToList();
              data = sortPara.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.strNumbers).ToList();
              data = sortPara.OrderByDescending(x => x).Select(x => x.strNumbers).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class SortPara : IComparable<SortPara>
    {
        public List<int> numbers { get; set; }
        public string strNumbers { get; set; }
        public SortPara(string strNumbers)
        {
            this.strNumbers = strNumbers;
            numbers = strNumbers.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();

        }
        public int CompareTo(SortPara other)
        {
            int shortest = this.numbers.Count < other.numbers.Count ? this.numbers.Count : other.numbers.Count;
            int results = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < shortest; i++)
            {
                if (this.numbers[i] != other.numbers[i])
                {
                    results = this.numbers[i].CompareTo(other.numbers[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is overkill for something like this

Comment: Only because there is a version method.  It is a good example of how to create a custom IComparable method using CompareTo() method.

Comment: @JackLe the only reason this is actually an overkill is that such methods already exists in latest C# libraries, but you may find this code snippet useful as whenever you need to compare `object x` to `object y` a custom `IComparable` interface must be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

know its an old thread but the easiest way is:

```
//list with some version numbers as strings
var versionList = new List<string>()
{
   "1.1.0",
   "1.10.0",
   "1.112.0",
}     
versionList.OrderByDescending(x => Version.Parse(x));
```

output: 
1.112.0 
1.10.0
1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

You should use `IComparable` as jdweng, just edit a bit to compare versions like "2.1.0.4" and "2.1":

```
public int CompareTo(SortPara other)
    {
        int shortest = this.numbers.Count < other.numbers.Count ? this.numbers.Count : other.numbers.Count;
        int results = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < shortest; i++)
        {
            if (this.numbers[i] != other.numbers[i])
            {
                results = this.numbers[i].CompareTo(other.numbers[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (results != 0)
            return results;
        if (this.numbers.Count > other.numbers.Count)
            return 1;
        else if (this.numbers.Count < other.numbers.Count)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you can omit all the if-else at the end by returning the two counts: return this.numbers.Count - other.numbers.Count;. If you return within the for loop you can remove the variable results and the break. To calculate the shortest use Math.Min(this.numbers.Count, other.numbers.Count);

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will sort Semantic Versioning (https://semver.org). **Nuget.Core** offers a **SemanticVersion** class that operates very similarly to the standard Version class in .net.  It will parse your string into an IComparable and IEquatable object so you can compare multiple versions or sort them within a collection, etc.

Nuget.Core:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/nuget.core/  (you can pull this library via nuget)

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.13/src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs

```
var rawVersions = new [] {"v1.4.0", "v1.4.0-patch10", "v1.4.0-patch2"};
var versions = rawVersions.Select(v => new SemanticVersion(v));
var sorted = versions.ToList().Sort();
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late answer. we can sort version number this way too. here is a small example.

```
var ver = new List<string>();
ver.Add("3.5");
ver.Add("3.15");
ver.Add("3.10");
ver.Add("3.1");

var OrderData = ver.Select(x => new
{
    version = x.ToString(),
    vorder = x.ToString().Replace(".", "")
}).OrderByDescending(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.vorder)).ToList();
```