# How to get elements in list and get next item using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

In my application I have **version** list which is string.
Json result looks like:

```
[
    "v2.9.0",
    "v2.10.0",
    "v2.11.0",
    "v2.12.0",
    "v2.13.0",
    "v2.14.0",
    "v2.15.0",
    "v2.16.0",
    "v2.1.0",
    "v2.2.0"
]
```

I am implementing upgrade version functionality. Which is upgrading currentVersion to targetVersion. Logic is for ex: if current version is **v2.9.0** it should be definitely upgrade to **2.10.0**  (trick part in our collection we have also **2.1.0**)

I have an idea to get data using this approach to getting max and min numbers but how to get logic for next number I have no idea.

```
           var str =  ReadLine();
           var digitArray = str.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList();
           var min = int.Parse(string.Concat<string>(digitArray.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => 
           x.ToString())));
           var max = int.Parse(string.Concat<string>(digitArray.OrderByDescending(x => 
           x).Select(x => x.ToString())));
```

My project class properties:

```
    public string KubesprayCurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public string KubesprayTargetVersion { get; set; }
```

My kubespray class properties which I am getting list of versions:

```
   public string Version { get; set; }
```

Getting list of version:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetKubesprays()
    {
        var result = await _context.Kubesprays.Select(x => x.Version).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

I need upgrade my project **kubeSprayTargetVersion** using list of kubespray version.
For saving I am using approach:

```
        [HttpPost("createproject")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProject(ProjectForCreationDto 
         projectForCreationDto)
        {
            var name = projectForCreationDto.Name.ToLower().Trim();
            var currentVerison = projectForCreationDto.KubesprayCurrentVersion.Trim();
            var targetVersion = string.Copy(currentVerison);

            if (await _repo.ProjectExists(name))
                return BadRequest("Project name already exists");

            var projectToCreate = new Project { Name = name, KubesprayCurrentVersion = 
            currentVerison, KubesprayTargetVersion = targetVersion};

            await _repo.CreateProject(projectToCreate);

            return StatusCode(201);
        }
```

I need upgrade **kubeSprayTargetVersion** to next one actually (in my case it is unsorted list first of all may be I need sort) (currently it is same **current** and **target**)

Something like **current** v2.9.0 => v2.10.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of many other questions ... search for natural sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with versions, why not use `Version` class?

```
  string[] data = new string[] {
    "v2.9.0", "v2.10.0", "v2.11.0", "v2.12.0", 
    "v2.13.0", "v2.14.0", "v2.15.0", "v2.16.0", 
    "v2.1.0", "v2.2.0"
  };

  string[] sorted = data
    .OrderBy(item => Version.Parse(Regex.Match(item, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+").Value))
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted));
```

Outcome:

```
v2.1.0
v2.2.0
v2.9.0
v2.10.0
v2.11.0
v2.12.0
v2.13.0
v2.14.0
v2.15.0
v2.16.0
```

Having the array *sorted*, you can easily find out neighbours (`"v2.9.0"` is followed by `"v2.10.0"` etc.):

```
  string currentVersion = "v2.9.0";

  string nextVersion = sorted[Array.IndexOf(sorted, currentVersion) + 1];
```

Comment: permutation of solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580830/how-to-sort-a-liststring-array-of-string-version-number#answer-37581023 ... you have enough reputation to close this question as duplicate