# Creating a custom sorting method for sorting version numbers using C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list versionNumbers =

```
v1.6.4
v2.1.19
v2.1.20
v2.10.00
v2.2.00
v2.2.01
v2.3.00
v2.4.00
v2.6.00
v2.4.01
```

After 2.9.00, the version should be 3.0.xx. But I have 2.10.00 and forward.

I tried System Sort() method and Orderby with Version.parse() method.
But they gave me wrong output:

```
v1.6.4
v2.1.19
v2.1.20
v2.10.00
v2.2.00
v2.2.01
v2.3.00
v2.4.00
v2.4.01
```

I am expecting 2.10.00 in the end and so on. What is the best way to sort such version numbering in C# and linq?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580830/how-to-sort-a-liststring-array-of-string-version-number

Comment: You can use the Version class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0 that implements `CompareTo`, so you can use `.Sort()` on a list of Version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `List<Version>`, then you can simple use `list.Sort()`. To get a version from a string use `Version.Parse`. Since you have a `v` in front you need to remove it:

```
List<string> versionStringList = new() {
    "v1.6.4",
    "v2.1.19",
    "v2.1.20",
    "v2.10.00",
    "v2.2.00",
    "v2.2.01",
    "v2.3.00",
    "v2.4.00",
    "v2.6.00",
    "v2.4.01"
};

List<Version> versionList = versionStringList
    .Select(s => Version.Parse(s.TrimStart('v', 'V')))
    .ToList();

versionList.Sort();
```

Result in debugger:

```
-       versionList Count = 10  System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Version>
+       [0] {1.6.4}  System.Version
+       [1] {2.1.19} System.Version
+       [2] {2.1.20} System.Version
+       [3] {2.2.0}  System.Version
+       [4] {2.2.1}  System.Version
+       [5] {2.3.0}  System.Version
+       [6] {2.4.0}  System.Version
+       [7] {2.4.1}  System.Version
+       [8] {2.6.0}  System.Version
+       [9] {2.10.0} System.Version
```

If you also don't know how to convert the `Version` afterwards to a formatted string, where the build number has always at least two digits, you can use this approach:

```
private static string VersionToString(Version v)
     => $"v{v.Major}.{v.Minor}.{v.Build.ToString("D2")}";
```

---

```
versionStringList = versionList.Select(VersionToString).ToList();
```

Comment: But this method removes extra digits in the output. Like, 2.4.01 becomes 2.4.1 and so on...
I want the string to be same.

Comment: @Walter: So you don't know how to convert the Version instance back to the desired string format?

Comment: I am new to this. I dont have much idea. @Tim Schmelter

Comment: I tried this: versionList.Select(x => x.ToString());

Comment: It would have been better to just OrderBy by Version.Parse (so basically replace Select with OrderBy), instead of converting between strings and Version and then back (and answer to duplicate already contains this approach).

Comment: @Evk: Yes, first i though OP will use the `Version` after parsing, but if it's just for ordering it's even simpler: `versionStringList=versionStringList.OrderBy(s => Version.Parse(s.TrimStart('v', 'V'))).ToList()`